# Is there an alternative for positive & negative lookahead and negative lookbehind for my REGEX that would work in Safari?

Tags: regex, google-chrome, safari

I have a REGEX to check the validity of a username which looks like this:

`/^(?=.{5,30}$)(?![_.-])(?!.*[_.-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(?<![_.-])$/`

Basically, my username has the following constraints:

- it should be 5-30 characters long,
- it can contain any alphanumeric [a-z A-Z 0-9] characters,
- it could contain symbols like _.-

  - it can't start or end with these symbols
  - the symbols can't be adjacent to each other

This REGEX works perfectly in Chrome, but as we all know, Safari doesn't support lookbehind in REGEX. However, I am not sure if they do support lookahead.

My question is, is there a way to convert this REGEX into something that Safari understands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may rephrase your regex as:

```
/^(?=.{5,30}$)(?![_.-])(?!.*[_.-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$/
                                                     ^^^ change is here
```

The logic I am using relies on that the only purpose of the negative lookbehind at the end of the pattern was to assert that the final character is *not* dot, underscore, or hyphen.  We can instead just use a character class to handle this.  Note that as a side-effect, the immediately previous character class becomes zero or more times, since now the one or more requirement would always be met by the final character.

Comment: Hi Tim! Thanks for the brilliant solution! Voted as the accepted answer! Seems like lookahead works in safari. Sadly, lookbehind is still not supported by Safari. Anyway, I think there is a typo in your answer, you might be referring to negative lookbehind and not negative lookahead. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression.

```
^(?=.{5,30}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9]*$
```

with the case-indifferent flag set.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^             match beginning of string
(?=.{5,30}$)  assert string contains 5-30 chars 
[a-z0-9]+     match 1+ alphanumeric chars
(?:           begin non-capture group
  [._-]       match one char in char class
  [a-z0-9]+   match 1+ chars in char class
)*            end non-cap group and execute 0+ times
[a-z0-9]*     match 0+ chars in char class
$             # match end of line
```